# Use of the word closure

Tags: probability

My probability book refers to the "support of the distribution of $X$" as the closure of the set $\{ x : f(x) > 0 \}$. I've looked up the definition but there seems to be quite a few uses for the word (namely an operation with two elements of a set yielding an element from the same set). Any information about which definition he is referring to would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's closure in the topological sense : the smallest closed set that contain your set